# How do you connect an amazon rds to a django app

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have added the correct name, engine, user, password etc. Then I modified the inbound security rules to give my computer access to the database and I still cant connect the postgres database to the django app does anyone know what could cause this?

I keep getting this error
port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Can you share ‘settings.py’ you use for the database. With dummy keys. Dont share the original ones.

Comment: sure, the settings are like this 'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
      'NAME':'dbname',
      'USER':'username',
      'PASSWORD':'pass',
      'HOST':'database.rds.amazonaws.com',
      'PORT':5432
   }

Comment: Try username :postgres. I had same issue even i kept username different. But et the end postgres worked

Comment: I just tried that it didnt work

Comment: Security groups?

Comment: Try to connect it using dbeaver. If inbound rules are fine. Than that connection should work

Comment: Did you configure it to be publicly accessible?

Comment: Yes I checked the inbound and outbound rules, I also made sure it was publicly accessible is there something else that could cause it to time out every time I try to connect?